# How to insert hyperlinks in Rich Text Box in RTF format

Tags: c#, winforms, rtf

I'm trying to insert a hyperlink to a Rich Text Box in WinForms (using .NET Framework 4.6.1). 
The way I'm doing it is asking both the URL and text to be inserted, and afterwards appending it to the rtb (I know it might be better to do it with a selected text, then only asking for the URL).

But when I try to append the RTF it's as if it wasn't appended at all. The way I append it is the following:

```cs
   string rtf = $"{{\\field{{\\*\\fldinst HYPERLINK \"{url}\"}}{{\\fldrslt {urlText}}}}}";
   richTb.Rtf += rtf;
```

I've also tried appending to `richTb.SelectionRtf` instead, but I got the same result. Am I missing something??

Comment: Rtf has a complex and nested structure. Appending to it will only work if you build it all up yourself. You should try to insert the new  content. Tricky! If you have placeholders it might get a lot easier..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For **WinForms** you can try to use [**LinkLabel**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.linklabel?view=netcore-3.1)

```
LinkLabel link = new LinkLabel();
link.Text = "Microsoft";
LinkLabel.Link data = new LinkLabel.Link();
data.LinkData = "https://www.microsoft.com/";
link.Links.Add(data);
link.Location = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.TextLength);
richTextBox1.Controls.Add(link);
```

For **WPF** you have to insert hyperlinks like [**Hyperlink**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.hyperlink?view=netcore-3.1) not like text:

```
Paragraph parx = new Paragraph();
Run run1 = new Run("Text preceeding the hyperlink.");
Run run2 = new Run("Text following the hyperlink.");
Run run3 = new Run("Link Text.");

Hyperlink hyperl = new Hyperlink(run3);
hyperl.NavigateUri = new Uri("http://search.msn.com");

parx.Inlines.Add(run1);
parx.Inlines.Add(hyperl);
parx.Inlines.Add(run2);
```

Adding a paragraph to the RichTextBox should look like

```
richTextBox1.IsDocumentEnabled = true;
richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Add(parx);
```

Comment: Sorry for asking, but how do I append the Paragraph object in the RTB? I tried searching for a bit but haven't found it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @Biel, I have updated the code. Hope that it will help :)

Comment: Thank you a lot @Boris Sokolov!! It does help, though I'm using WinForms and I guess that might be WPF, since the IsDocumentEnabled option doesn't show up for me. It was really helpful though!

Comment: Please don't be sorry at all!! I'm super thankful for all your help :)! And now I know how to do it both for WinForms and WPF! :P Thank you again.